# Model not change. multiple ng-repeat and checkbox in last of them.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

If I have multiple ng-repeat and checkbox in last of them, all checkboxes are checked if I push one of them. How to resolve the problem?

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="(ctIndex, ct) in cts">
  <div ng-repeat="cs in ct track by $index">
     <!-- One checkbox: using ng-checked in place of ng-model --> 
     <div ng-repeat="(tId, task) in cs">
        <input type="checkbox" id="taskChecked{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}_{{tId}}" data-ng-change="checkTask(ctIndex, $index, tId)" name="task{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}_{{tId}}" data-ng-model="task.selected">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Solved with @ManojLodhi's answer, but now I have another problem. The model doesn't change (true or false) to "task.selected"

Comment: [Off-topic] Having so many nested ng-repeats is not good for performance. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/1921/profiling-and-performance/6270/7-simple-performance-improvements#t=201612130857439560856)

Comment: you can use ng-checked in place of ng-model if you only want to show selected as selected.

Comment: @ManojLodhi I have resolve the problem with your response. But now, I have another one. I have one more checkbox in second ng-repeat. For this I solved the problem but not for last of them.

Comment: @ManojLodhi, I solved the problem. I had ng-change in last checkbox. I have changed by ng-click. Thanks

Comment: @vicenrele Welcome :)

Comment: @ManojLodhi , but now I have another problem. The model doesn't change (true or false) to "task.selected"

Comment: @vicenrele then it should be the js that have issue

Comment: @arufian I have 3 ng-repeats and 2 checkboxes in. I haven't JS problem

Answer (score 1):

All your checkboxes connect to the same property in your model:

```
data-ng-model="task.selected"
```

You need independent model properties for independent checkboxes.